# How to add vertice names for the adjacency matrices?

Tags: diagrams, matrices, graphs

I decided to combine two adjacency matrices  into one in order to save space. 
 However, how can I add the vertex names to the matrix? 
Also please suggest if you have any idea to improve or better way to show the two adjacency matrices.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

$\textcolor{red}{A_{1}}/\textcolor{blue}{A_{2}}=\begin{pmatrix}
    \textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{1}&\textcolor{red}{1}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{1}&\textcolor{red}{1}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{1}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{1}\\
    \textcolor{red}{1}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{1}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{1}&\textcolor{red}{1}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{0}\\
    \textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{1}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{1}&\textcolor{red}{1}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{1}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{1}\\
    \textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{1}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{1}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{1}\\
    \textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{1}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{1}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{1}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{1}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{1}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{1}\\
    \textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{1}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{0}&\textcolor{red}{0}/\textcolor{blue}{0}\\
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: One easy way is to use `nicematrix`. A quick search should give you hints (or even a solution)

Comment: @SebGlav I'll check if it works. Btw, do you have any idea to simpify the code with `\textcolor{red}{}/\textcolor{blue}{}`? I think it's possible to make a command for this.

Comment: Do this: `\newcommand{\clr}[2]{\textcolor{red}{#1}/\textcolor{blue}{#2}}`, then call it like this: `\clr{0}{1}`. The name `\clr` can be changed to whatever you want.